# Private transactions

Tags: substrate

After watching [Gavin's talk](https://youtu.be/iUMZyL5kTwc?t=2501) where he mentions private transactions in the Q&A, I started looking into if it's a thing on Substrate. I found [this Parity Ethereum wiki article](https://wiki.parity.io/Private-Transactions.html) describing something similar. Is this currently possible on Substrate?

edit: I want to create encrypted transactions that only a selected number of peers can view. For each transaction this set might change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such solution on Substrate as of the time of writing this post.

There are some *privacy* layers which are being built on Substrate such as [Zero Chain](https://github.com/LayerXcom/zero-chain):

> Zerochain is a generic privacy-protecting layer on top of Substrate. It provides some useful substrate modules and toolkit for protecting user's privacy and sensitive data stored on chain. It is designed to get efficient zero-knowledge proving, reduce the on-chain storage cost and bring the flexibility for developing applications.

I don't think however, this attempts to solve the problem you are exactly describing.